# React router behaviour with google cached pages.

Tags: reactjs, seo, react-router, google-search, google-search-console

We have recently ported our application from monolithic RubyOnRails to React/Redux Framework.
We are facing a problem with react-router and google cached pages in the results of google. In this case we have a SPA(single page application), which uses react-router (via browserHistory). The problem here is that: google cached page is a page wrapper, where the URL differs by the URL defined in the router of the SPA. So, in this case the routing of the application falls to the definition of a page not found. And the cached result of SPA page by google, instead showing the content of the page, page is reloaded to /search (wrapper path).

React Router Version: 3.0.3
React Version: 15.4.2

Here is how we have handled the generic Urls:

```
<Route onEnter={hitTheServer}>
  <Route path="*" component={Home} />
</Route>
```

hitTheServer definition:

> ```
> const hitTheServer = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
>   const url = `https://${config.server.public.host}${nextState.location.pathname}`;
>   // Hit the server only on client side rendering. A hack to handle unimplemented pages
>   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
>     window.location = url;
>   } else {
>     cb();
>   }
> };
> ```

Here, we are doing page reload because there are some of the links are still not implement by out SPA, so, on full page reload, these links are router to their respective server (rails or node) via nginx.